Transplant problems and solution from svmono.cls
for a new textbook I would like to include example problems and their solution at the end of each chapter. The styles for producing exam sheets (with randomly mixed options, order of question and the like) are overkill for this.
Since the preferred scrbook class does not provide for problem sections, I have tried to extract them from svmono.cls (Springer book template). This produces the expected results, but also a hail of error messages that I as a humble LaTeX user (as opposed to TeX programmer) do not understand. What am I missing?
  % !Mode:: "TeX:UK:UTF-8"
  % !TEX program = XeLaTeX
  % -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[a4paper,british,final]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Definition of the "\spnewtheorem" command from svmono.cls (https://dam.springernature.com/file/B9DCMjesqTi9--5PvAbAip/*/svmono.zip?authcred=Q29weVVSTDpDMHB5X1VSTA==)
%
% Usage:
%
%     \spnewtheorem{env_nam}{caption}[within]{cap_font}{body_font}
% or  \spnewtheorem{env_nam}[numbered_like]{caption}{cap_font}{body_font}
% or  \spnewtheorem*{env_nam}{caption}{cap_font}{body_font}
%
% New is "cap_font" and "body_font". It stands for
% fontdefinition of the caption and the text itself.
%
% "\spnewtheorem*" gives a theorem without number.
%
% A defined spnewthoerem environment is used as described
% by Lamport.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\@thmcountersep{.}
\def\@thmcounterend{.}
\newcommand\nocaption{\noexpand\@gobble}
\newdimen\spthmsep \spthmsep=3pt

\def\spnewtheorem{\@ifstar{\@sthm}{\@Sthm}}

% definition of \spnewtheorem with number

\def\@spnthm#1#2{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\@spxnthm{#1}{#2}}{\@spynthm{#1}{#2}}}
\def\@Sthm#1{\@ifnextchar[{\@spothm{#1}}{\@spnthm{#1}}}

\def\@spxnthm#1#2[#3]#4#5{\expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #1\endcsname
   {\@definecounter{#1}\@addtoreset{#1}{#3}%
   \expandafter\xdef\csname the#1\endcsname{\expandafter\noexpand
     \csname the#3\endcsname \noexpand\@thmcountersep \@thmcounter{#1}}%
   \expandafter\xdef\csname #1name\endcsname{#2}%
   \global\@namedef{#1}{\@spthm{#1}{\csname #1name\endcsname}{#4}{#5}}%
                              \global\@namedef{end#1}{\@endtheorem}}}

\def\@spynthm#1#2#3#4{\expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #1\endcsname
   {\@definecounter{#1}%
   \expandafter\xdef\csname the#1\endcsname{\@thmcounter{#1}}%
   \expandafter\xdef\csname #1name\endcsname{#2}%
   \global\@namedef{#1}{\@spthm{#1}{\csname #1name\endcsname}{#3}{#4}}%
                               \global\@namedef{end#1}{\@endtheorem}}}

\def\@spothm#1[#2]#3#4#5{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#2}{\@latexerr{No theorem environment `#2' defined}\@eha}%
  {\expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #1\endcsname
  {\global\@namedef{the#1}{\@nameuse{the#2}}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname #1name\endcsname{#3}%
  \global\@namedef{#1}{\@spthm{#2}{\csname #1name\endcsname}{#4}{#5}}%
  \global\@namedef{end#1}{\@endtheorem}}}}

\def\@spthm#1#2#3#4{\topsep 7\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
\labelsep=\spthmsep\refstepcounter{#1}%
\@ifnextchar[{\@spythm{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}{\@spxthm{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}}

\def\@spxthm#1#2#3#4{\@spbegintheorem{#2}{\csname the#1\endcsname}{#3}{#4}%
                    \ignorespaces}

\def\@spythm#1#2#3#4[#5]{\@spopargbegintheorem{#2}{\csname
       the#1\endcsname}{#5}{#3}{#4}\ignorespaces}

\def\normalthmheadings{\def\@spbegintheorem##1##2##3##4{\trivlist
                 \item[\hskip\labelsep{##3##1\ ##2\@thmcounterend}]##4}
\def\@spopargbegintheorem##1##2##3##4##5{\trivlist
      \item[\hskip\labelsep{##4##1\ ##2}]{##4(##3)\@thmcounterend\ }##5}}
\normalthmheadings

\def\reversethmheadings{\def\@spbegintheorem##1##2##3##4{\trivlist
                 \item[\hskip\labelsep{##3##2\ ##1\@thmcounterend}]##4}
\def\@spopargbegintheorem##1##2##3##4##5{\trivlist
      \item[\hskip\labelsep{##4##2\ ##1}]{##4(##3)\@thmcounterend\ }##5}}

% definition of \spnewtheorem* without number

\def\@sthm#1#2{\@Ynthm{#1}{#2}}

\def\@Ynthm#1#2#3#4{\expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname #1\endcsname
   {\global\@namedef{#1}{\@Thm{\csname #1name\endcsname}{#3}{#4}}%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname #1name\endcsname{#2}%
    \global\@namedef{end#1}{\@endtheorem}}}

\def\@Thm#1#2#3{\topsep 7\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
\@ifnextchar[{\@Ythm{#1}{#2}{#3}}{\@Xthm{#1}{#2}{#3}}}

\def\@Xthm#1#2#3{\@Begintheorem{#1}{#2}{#3}\ignorespaces}

\def\@Ythm#1#2#3[#4]{\@Opargbegintheorem{#1}
       {#4}{#2}{#3}\ignorespaces}

\def\@Begintheorem#1#2#3{#3\trivlist
                           \item[\hskip\labelsep{#2#1\@thmcounterend}]}

\def\@Opargbegintheorem#1#2#3#4{#4\trivlist
      \item[\hskip\labelsep{#3#1}]{#3(#2)\@thmcounterend\ }}

% initialize theorem environment

\if@envcntshowhiercnt % show hierarchy counter
   \def\@thmcountersep{.}
   \spnewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[\envankh]{\bfseries}{\itshape}
   \@addtoreset{theorem}{chapter}
\else          % theorem counter only
   \spnewtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
   \if@envcntreset
      \@addtoreset{theorem}{chapter}
      \if@envcntresetsect
         \@addtoreset{theorem}{section}
      \fi
   \fi
\fi

%definition of divers theorem environments
\spnewtheorem*{claim}{Claim}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\spnewtheorem*{proof}{Proof}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
%
\if@envcntsame % all environments like "Theorem" - using its counter
   \def\spn@wtheorem#1#2#3#4{\@spothm{#1}[theorem]{#2}{#3}{#4}}
\else % all environments with their own counter
   \if@envcntshowhiercnt % show hierarchy counter
      \def\spn@wtheorem#1#2#3#4{\@spxnthm{#1}{#2}[\envankh]{#3}{#4}}
   \else          % environment counter only
      \if@envcntreset % environment counter is reset each section
         \if@envcntresetsect
            \def\spn@wtheorem#1#2#3#4{\@spynthm{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
             \@addtoreset{#1}{chapter}\@addtoreset{#1}{section}}
         \else
            \def\spn@wtheorem#1#2#3#4{\@spynthm{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
                                      \@addtoreset{#1}{chapter}}
         \fi
      \else
         \let\spn@wtheorem=\@spynthm
      \fi
   \fi
\fi
%
\let\spdefaulttheorem=\spn@wtheorem
%
\spn@wtheorem{case}{Case}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spn@wtheorem{definition}{Definition}{\bfseries}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{example}{Example}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}{\bfseries}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spn@wtheorem{note}{Note}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{problem}{Problem}{\bfseries}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{property}{Property}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}{\bfseries}{\itshape}
\spn@wtheorem{question}{Question}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{solution}{Solution}{\bfseries}{\rmfamily}
\spn@wtheorem{remark}{Remark}{\itshape}{\rmfamily}
%
\newenvironment{theopargself}
    {\def\@spopargbegintheorem##1##2##3##4##5{\trivlist
         \item[\hskip\labelsep{##4##1\ ##2}]{##4##3\@thmcounterend\ }##5}
     \def\@Opargbegintheorem##1##2##3##4{##4\trivlist
         \item[\hskip\labelsep{##3##1}]{##3##2\@thmcounterend\ }}}{}
\newenvironment{theopargself*}
    {\def\@spopargbegintheorem##1##2##3##4##5{\trivlist
         \item[\hskip\labelsep{##4##1\ ##2}]{\hspace*{-\labelsep}##4##3\@thmcounterend}##5}
     \def\@Opargbegintheorem##1##2##3##4{##4\trivlist
         \item[\hskip\labelsep{##3##1}]{\hspace*{-\labelsep}##3##2\@thmcounterend}}}{}
%
\spn@wtheorem{prob}{\nocaption}{\bfseries}{\rmfamily}
\newcommand{\probref}[1]{\textbf{\ref{#1}} }
\newenvironment{sol}{\par\addvspace{6pt}\noindent\probref}{\par\addvspace{6pt}}
%
\fi

\def\@takefromreset#1#2{%
    \def\@tempa{#1}%
    \let\@tempd\@elt
    \def\@elt##1{%
        \def\@tempb{##1}%
        \ifx\@tempa\@tempb\else
            \@addtoreset{##1}{#2}%
        \fi}%
    \expandafter\expandafter\let\expandafter\@tempc\csname cl@#2\endcsname
    \expandafter\def\csname cl@#2\endcsname{}%
    \@tempc
    \let\@elt\@tempd}


\title{Test}
\author{Tester}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter{First chapter}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Exercises}

\subsection{Problems}

\begin{prob}
  \label{problem:FA3}
  A patient is on chitosan to help him reduce weight. He may have to supplement his diet with which of the following compounds?  
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item{Retinal}
    \item{Folate}
    \item{Nicotinamide}
    \item{Riboflavine}
    \item{Biotin}
  \end{enumerate}  
\end{prob}

\subsection{Solutions}

\begin{sol}{problem:FA3}
  Retinal is hydrophobic and fat soluble. Hence its uptake may be reduced by the ``fat blocker'' chitosan. Biotin, folate, nicotinamide and riboflavin are water-soluble, chitosan will not interfere with their uptake.
\end{sol}

\end{document}

The first of 15 error messages is
\spnewtheorem ->\@i
                   fstar{\@sthm}{\@Sthm}
l.115    \spnewtheorem
                      {theorem}{Theorem}{\bfseries}{\itshape} 


You can try with the package answers.sty package for your requirement, refer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413303/answers-in-a-line-with-answers-package for more clarification

What is the first error or warning message that you get? Please edit your question to include that information. When that is solved you can go to the next issue (or, if you are lucky, solving the first problem will also resolve all other issues, as errors tend to propagate and warnings tend to reproduce).

Ah now I see (based on the error message): you forgot to put \makeatletter and \makeatother around the code that you copied from the class file. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do.

Yes, thanks, that solves most errors. The others require some definitions from svmono.cls copied.

I don't think you need such a difficult transplant.
\documentclass[a4paper,british,final]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheoremstyle{problem}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {\thmnumber{#2}}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\theoremstyle{problem}
\newtheorem{prob}{}[subsection]
\renewcommand{\theprob}{\arabic{prob}}
\newtheorem{innersol}{}
\newenvironment{sol}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\theinnersol}{\ref{#1}}%
  \innersol
}{%
  \endinnersol
}

\title{Test}
\author{Tester}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter{First chapter}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Exercises}

\subsection{Problems}

\begin{prob}
  \label{problem:FA3}
  A patient is on chitosan to help him reduce weight. He may have to supplement his diet with which of the following compounds?  
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item{Retinal}
    \item{Folate}
    \item{Nicotinamide}
    \item{Riboflavine}
    \item{Biotin}
  \end{enumerate}  
\end{prob}

\subsection{Solutions}

\begin{sol}{problem:FA3}
  Retinal is hydrophobic and fat soluble. Hence its uptake may be reduced by the ``fat blocker'' chitosan. Biotin, folate, nicotinamide and riboflavin are water-soluble, chitosan will not interfere with their uptake.
\end{sol}

\end{document}



A much simpler solution, indeed. Thanks very much!

@EngelbertBuxbaum If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider upvoting (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the accepted answer (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). And please also don't forget the answers to your other questions.
